# Using FakeJSON in my ReactApp returns "Error - missing token"

Tags: reactjs, api

Has anyone used the site app.fakejson.com to get sample data for their application?

I'm creating a post request as stated in their site but it returns an error "Error - token missing", although the token is within the data payload in POST.

```
    const fetch2body = JSON.stringify({
      token: '<mytokeninhere>',
      data: {
        name: 'name',
        numberInt: 'numberInt',
        dateTime: "dateTime|UNIX",
        stringLong: "stringLong",
        fileName: 'fileName',
        fileExtension: 'fileExtension',
        productOrderStatus: 'productOrderStatus',
        _repeat: 25
      }
    });

    try {
      const datafetch2 = await fetch(
        'https://app.fakejson.com/q',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          data: fetch2body });
     const actualdata2 = await datafetch2.json();
      console.log(actualdata2);

   catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
```

Comment: why `JSON.stringify`? shouldn't you just pass the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with stringifying the response ([MDN example on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Uploading_JSON_data)).

The problem with your code is that you are using the wrong parameter to send data. Change `data` to `body`.

Instead of this:

```js
const datafetch2 = await fetch(
  'https://app.fakejson.com/q',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      // data is not a valid parameter
      data: fetch2body
    }
);
```

You should use the `body` parameter, like this:

```js
const datafetch2 = await fetch(
  'https://app.fakejson.com/q',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      // body is the correct parameter
      body: fetch2body
    }
);
```

You can read more about it on [Mozilla `fetch` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You are `stringify`-ing the json object and sending it to the endpoint.
Just send the pure json object and it should be ok (taking into consideration that all other fields/validations are OK)

```
const fetch2body = {
  token: '<mytokeninhere>',
  data: {
    name: 'name',
    numberInt: 'numberInt',
    dateTime: "dateTime|UNIX",
    stringLong: "stringLong",
    fileName: 'fileName',
    fileExtension: 'fileExtension',
    productOrderStatus: 'productOrderStatus',
    _repeat: 25
  }
};
```